# How to stop/pause the video by clicking on Close button

Tags: jquery

I am tried using jQuery code to pause the video by clicking on the close (X) button. But its not working. Please help me with correct code how to do this. I have following code.

```
<div class="popup__overlay">
    <div id="popupVid" class="popup">
        <a class="close">X</a>
        <br />
        <video id="framevideo" controls="controls" width="500">
            <source src="https://eocares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Website-version1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <br />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(".close").click(function() {
    jQuery('video')[0].pause();
});
```

Comment: For playing use `$('#framevideo')[0].play();`  & for pausing `$('#framevideo')[0].pause();`

Comment: Your code is working fine for for pause. You want something else?

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: i dont know why its not working at my end

Comment: Your code is working fine. check error and jquery library include before script

Comment: I have updated your code. But still you have to check any error occurring on your side.

Comment: I checked your code is working fine for me. are you getting any error on console ?

Comment: remember your $(document).ready(function(){ //code })

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

If you to play and pause video on click here is simple code to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var click = 0;
   $('video')[0].play();
   $(".close").click(function() {
    if ( parseInt(click) % 2 == 0 ) {
          $('video')[0].pause();
    } else {
        $('video')[0].play();
    }
     click++;

  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already ready, please check have called properly in your code.
i have updated you same code but i have applied some CSS style and called Jquery library file.

```js
$(".close").click(function() {
    $('video')[0].pause();
});
```

```css
.popup__overlay{
      width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.popup__overlay video{width:100%;}
.close{
      position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #e2dddd;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 1px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup__overlay">
    <div id="popupVid" class="popup">
        <a class="close">X</a>
        <br />
        <video id="framevideo" controls="controls" width="500">
            <source src="https://eocares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Website-version1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <br />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```